# Drawing multiple images on Canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, drawable

I am trying to draw multiple images on a canvas and display it but I just don't know how to.

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
private Drawable mDrawable;
private Drawable mD2;

public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    int x = 40;
    int y = 100;
    int width = 20;
    int height = 10;

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    mDrawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.main);
    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

    mD2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.virus);
    mD2.setBounds(x+50,y-70,width+10,height+5);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
    mD2.draw(canvas2);
}
}
```

Comment: You dont need to create a new instance of a canvas, just do
md2.draw(canvas).

Comment: I tried that... but it didn't work. Thats why I thought maybe 2 canvases would work...

Comment: what happens when you draw only mDrawable, and then only md2, do they show?

Comment: Actually it works... Thank you so much... I just had the height and width wrong...

Comment: I added the answer in case you want to give me credit for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to create a new instance of a canvas, just do md2.draw(canvas). And also you may try:

what happens when you draw only mDrawable, and then only md2, do they show?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't worked with Drawables on a Canvas, but I can tell your for sure that with bitmaps it works just fine like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1,0,0,myPaint); // draws in top left corner
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2,100,100, myPaint); // draws at an offset of 100 px on both the X and the Y axis
```